EvtQuery call - "Error_Access_Denied"
I have successfully used EvtQuery() to read Windows events in the past (Delphi 10.3 & Windows 7), but coming back to it after a few years (now using Delphi 11.3 & Windows 10).
In the code below, EvtQuery() returns 0, and GetLastError returns 5 (which is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED).
program EvtQueryTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

type
  EVT_HANDLE = type THandle;

function EvtQuery(Session: EVT_HANDLE; Path, Query: PWideChar; Flags: DWORD): EVT_HANDLE;stdcall; external 'wevtapi.dll';

procedure TestEvtQuery;
// See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/querying-for-events

const
  EvtQueryChannelPath = $1;
  EvtQueryReverseDirection = $200;

var
  Path, Query : string;
  HostHandle, EventLogHandle : EVT_Handle;

begin
  Path := 'Security';
  Query :=  '<QueryList><Query Path="Security"><Select>Event/System[EventID=4625]</Select></Query></QueryList>';
  HostHandle := 0;

  EventLogHandle := EvtQuery(HostHandle, PWideChar(Path), PWideChar(Query), EvtQueryChannelPath + EvtQueryReverseDirection);
  if (EventLogHandle <> 0) then writeln('success !') else Writeln('ERROR Code: ' + IntToStr(GetLastError));
  readln;
Close(EventLogHandle);
end;

begin
  TestEvtQuery;
end.

This is all in the context of the local machine. So, I do not need any credential validation is my understanding. I expect the code to return a handle without an Access Violation error. What am I missing?
Edit #1:
Copied below is the full code that I use
    FEventLogHandle := EvtQuery.WinEvtDefs.EvtQuery(FHostHandle, PWideChar(FPath), PWideChar(FQuery), EvtQueryChannelPath + EvtQueryReverseDirection);
    result := (FEventLogHandle <> 0);
    if result then
    begin
      FEvent := TEvtEvent.Create(hSysContext, hUsrContext, FEventReaderMode);
      FEvent.UseXmlMode := XmlMode;
    end
    else
    begin
      Status := GetLastError;
      if (Status = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) then HandleEvtError('[E11A] - Access Denied'#13#10 + FPath + #13#10 + FQuery + #13#10, Status, false, true)
      else if (Status = ERROR_EVT_CHANNEL_NOT_FOUND) then HandleEvtError('[E11B] ' + pwsPath + ' is NOT a valid event channel', Status)
      else if (status = ERROR_EVT_INVALID_QUERY) then
      begin
       /// We can call the EvtGetExtendedStatus function to try to get
       /// additional information as to what is wrong with the query.
       HandleEvtError('[E12] ' + pwsQuery + ' is NOT a valid event query', Status);
      end
      else HandleEvtError('[E13] EvtQuery Failed', status);
    end;


Is EvtQuery the Ansi version of the API, or the Unicode one? The access violation could be related to the PWideChar castings.

@AntonioPetricca, I think functions in winevt.h are Unicode. I do not see "A" & "W" versions there. Reference at link

@ss2006 correct, EvtQuery() is Unicode-only, there is no ANSI version.

@ss2006 I don't see anything wrong with your call to EvtQuery() that would cause an AccessViolation, are you sure that is what you are actually getting? Can you [edit] your question to show the actual error you are seeing? In any case, the only thing I do see incorrect is if (EventLogHandle > 0) should be if (EventLogHandle <> 0) instead, and also if EvtQuery() were successful then you need to call EvtClose() to avoid leaking the EVT_HANDLE.

@ss2006 I just ran your code in Delphi 12.1 on Windows 10, and did not get an AccessViolation.  However, EvtQuery() fails with error code 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED), unless I run the app with admin rights, then it works fine. Is that maybe what you are actually seeing instead? An AccessViolation exception and an AccessDenied error code are two completely different things.

@RemyLebeau. I edited the question to fix my mistake. The problem is exactly what you noted. It is not Access Violation, but ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. EvtQuery returns 0, and the call to GetLastError returns a 5. I have added my actual source in the the question (at the bottom as Edit #1).

@RemyLebeau, I am running as administrator (well logging into an admin account), but not running as "Elevated". I can open EventVwr.exe and browse these events, so shouldn't I be able to read them via EvtQuery with the same user rights?

@ss2006 logging into an admin user, and running as in elevated state, are two different things. It is entirely possible (I haven't checked) that EventVwr could be running elevated without prompting you for access. Some Microsoft system tools do that.

@RemyLebeau, Didn't know MS tools could elevate without prompting. Is it possible for me to Elevate without prompting (using Delphi)? Appreciate any pointers, or links. I have found [this link] (https://github.com/eversonturossi/delphi/tree/master/Executa%20como%20adm/Runas%20Admin%20Elevated%20UAC%20ShellExecute%20Delphi) but it spawns a new process with prompting

@ss2006 "Is it possible for me to Elevate without prompting?" - no, it is not possible. That would render UAC useless if you could. Microsoft makes exceptions for some of its own tools.

Okay, that makes sense. But is there any documentation that says these functions now require administrator rights? They seem to have worked fine with ordinary user credentials in Windows 7. I could not find any reference to such a change in the documentation. If this question/follow up does not provide useful info, please feel free to delete it.
